# statement_mem seems to limit the node memory instead of the segment memory

Tags: greenplum

According to the GreenPlum documentation, GUCs such as statement_mem, gp_vmem_protect_limit should work at segment level. Same thing should happen with a resource queue memory allowance.

On our system we have 8 primary segments per node. So if I set the statement_mem of a query to 2GB I would expect the query to consume (if needed) up to 2GB x 8 = 16GBs of RAM. But it seems that it would only use 2GBs total per node before starting to write into disk (that's it 2GB/8 per segment). I tried with different statement_values and same thing.

max_statement_mem or gp_vmem_protect_limit limits are never reached. RAM usage on nodes have been monitored using various tools (from GP command center to top, free, all the way across Pivotal suggested session_level_memory_consumption view).

EDITED FROM HERE

ADDED two documentation sources where statement_mem is defined per segment and not per host. (@Jon Roberts)

On the GP best practices guide, beginning of page 32, it clearly says that if the statement_mem is 125MB and we have 8 segments on the server, each query will get 1GB allocated per server.

https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwi6sOTx8O3KAhVBKg4KHTwICX0QFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgpdb.docs.pivotal.io%2F4300%2Fpdf%2FGPDB43BestPractices.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGkTqa6143fvJUztYISWAiVyj62dA&sig2=D2ZcJwLDqN0qBzU73NjXNg&bvm=bv.113943164,d.ZWU&cad=rja

On the https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201947018-Pivotal-Greenplum-GPDB-Memory-Configuration it seems to use statement_mem as segment memory and not host memory. It keeps interrelating statement_mem with the memory limit of the resource queues as well as with the gp_vmem_protect_limit (both parameters defined per segment basis).

This is why I'm getting confused about how to properly manage the memory resources.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I incorrectly stated that statement_mem is on a per host and that is not the case.  This link is talking about the memory on a segment level:
http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4370/guc_config-statement_mem.html#statement_mem

With the default of "eager_free" gp_resqueue_memory_policy, memory gets re-used so the aggregate amount of memory used may look low for a particular query execution.  If you change it to "auto" where the memory isn't re-used, the memory usage is more noticeable.

Run an "explain analyze" of your query and see the slices that are used.  With eager_free, the memory gets re-used so you may only have a single slice wanting more memory than available such as this one:

```
(slice18) * Executor memory: 10399K bytes avg x 2 workers, 10399K bytes max (seg0).  Work_mem: 8192K bytes max, 13088K bytes wanted.
```

And for your question on how to manage the resources, most people don't change the default values.  A query that spills to disk is usually an indication that the query needs to be revised or the data model needs some work.

Comment: That statement_mem allocates RAM per host basis, in our case,it is a fact. But Pivotal documentation regarding this GUC seems misleading.
On the first link you provided, the statement_mem gets compared to gp_vmem_protect_limit by assuming that a reasonable value for the statement_mem could be the following:

( gp_vmem_protect_limitGB * .9 ) / max_expected_concurrent_queries

But when checking the definition of gp_vmem_protect_limit, we can see it gets calculated by segment and not by host.
http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4370/guc_config-gp_vmem_protect_limit.html#gp_vmem_protect_limit

Comment: I've set the gp_resqueue_memory_policy to "auto" and tested the statement_mem. It's not that much noticeable if it sets the host or the segment memory, what makes its use quite counter-intuitive. As you said, the solution might be to run explain analyze per each query and increase the mem if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what's the final word on this? We are also wondering how to set statement mem properly. When running explain analyze, should we set to the total memory wanted or multiply the total memory wanted by number of hosts and or segment hosts?